# JSONObjcet with String array toString() output has integer values instead of strings

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to save `List<String>` as string, but the conversion gives me `JSONArray` having `Integer` values.

So the output is this:

```
{"data":"{\"my_array\":[\"[41, 14]\"]}"}
```

What i want:

```
{"data":"{\"my_array\":[\"[\"41\", \"14\"]\"]}"}
```

The first output is okay for Java environment, but iOS needs the values to be "Strings".

Little update: I believe that `JSONObject.toString()` messes this up. The next code:

```
    List<String> test = Arrays.asList("41", "14");
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    try {
        root.put("my_array", test);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
    }
```

Results in :  `{"my_array":"[41, 14]"}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSONArray`.

```
 public void test__aaaa(){
        try {
            List<String> test = Arrays.asList("41", "14");

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(test);

            JSONObject root  = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            root.put("data", data);

            data.put("my_array", array);

            assertEquals(root.toString(), "{\"data\":{\"my_array\":[\"41\",\"14\"]}}");

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
        }
    }
```

On Android if we put `list` as Object, Json convert it to String as is, so we get `"[41,14]"`.

Comment: import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject; {"data":{"my_array":"[41, 14]"}}

Comment: do you use `java-json`?

Comment: That was the output with your example for me. So is this Java problem or what? Where does org.json come from? My android sdk min target is 8

Comment: Oh man, thank for additional info about Android. See my answer, it should work now

Comment: Very good job, now the example gives me: {"data":{"my_array":["41","14"]}}

Comment: Wow so this was purely about Android sucking once again.